# fill a form in a asp dynamic page with htmlunit

Tags: java, web-scraping, htmlunit

I'm making a little script in java to check iPhone IMEI numbers.
There is this site from Apple : 
https://appleonlinefra.mpxltd.co.uk/search.aspx

You have to enter an IMEI number. If this number is OK, it drives you to this page : 
https://appleonlinefra.mpxltd.co.uk/Inspection.aspx
Else, you stay on **/search.aspx** page
I want to open the search page, enter an IMEI, submit, and check if the URL has changed. In my code there is a working IMEI number.

Here is my java code :

```
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://appleonlinefra.mpxltd.co.uk/search.aspx");

HtmlTextInput imei_input = (HtmlTextInput)page.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtIMEIVal");

imei_input.setValueAttribute("012534008614194");

//HtmlAnchor check_imei = page.getAnchorByText("Rechercher");
//Tried with both ways of getting the anchor, none works

HtmlAnchor anchor1 = (HtmlAnchor)page.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_imeiValidate");
page = anchor1.click();

System.out.println(page.getUrl());
```

I can't find out where it comes from, since i often use HTMLUnit for this and i never had this issue. Maybe because of the little loading time after submiting ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a connection wrapper that HTMLUnit provides

Here is an example

```
    new WebConnectionWrapper(webClient) {

        public WebResponse getResponse(WebRequest request) throws IOException {
            WebResponse response = super.getResponse(request);
            if (request.getUrl().toExternalForm().contains("Inspection.aspx")) {
                String content = response.getContentAsString("UTF-8");

                WebResponseData data = new WebResponseData(content.getBytes("UTF-8"), response.getStatusCode(),
                        response.getStatusMessage(), response.getResponseHeaders());
                response = new WebResponse(data, request, response.getLoadTime());
            }
            return response;
        }
    };
```

With the connection wrapper above, you can check for any request and response that is passing through HTMLUnit

Comment: Tried to find documentation about the connection wrapper, hard to me to understand it and also your code. I'm trying to adapt it to my situation, but i can't find out out to do